# Is it possible to zoom map?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

Is it possible to zoom while viewing map?

<kbd>Z</kbd> works for general camera, but doesn't do so when map is opened. It's so frustrating - all devices are on the map, but icons are too small to be useful!